# Red Hat 6.5- sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects=0

Tags: redhat, redirect, ipv6, kickstart

I am in the process of writing a Red Hat 6.5 Kickstart disc with hardened security. I have run a program to determine where the weaknesses are in my system, and apparently there is a medium severity problem by accepting IPV6 redirects.

When I implement the following line in my post script in my kickstart, I can't access any websites externally with wget, or ssh/scp in from my computer.

`sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects=0`

Is there a workaround to this so that the system will still be hardened but I will be able to access systems that are external?

Comment: It's possible you are on a network that requires redirects for some reason.